# laravel ajax get request on orderBy => internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax, laravel

i'd like to performe a simple "orderBy" data from mssql server table with an ajax request...
but i get an Internal Server Error 500

heres my route:

```
Route::get('intranet_admin/gestioneStatoUtenti/rotte', 'UserController@orderByDrop');
```

here's my controller:

```
public function orderByDrop(){
    $selectedValue = Input::get('filter_id');

        $fetchFilter = User::orderBy($selectedValue)->get();

        return Response::json($fetchFilter);
}
```

here's my view:

```
 <div class="large-3 columns">

        <select name="filter_id" id="filterValue">
              <option value="TLK">Tlk</option>
              <option value="StatoUtent">Stato Utente</option>
              <option value="CodFisc">Codice Fiscale</option>
              <option value="IdUtente">Id Utente</option>

        </select>


    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function($){

    $('#filterValue').change(function(e){
            console.log(e);
            var filter_id = e.target.value;

            $.get('gestioneStatoUtenti/rotte?filter_id='+ filter_id, function(data){

                        console.log(data);

            });
    });

     });
    </script>
```

cheers

Comment: What does your Users-table look like?

Comment: IdUtente|| TLK || StatoUtent || CodFisc || .. something like this

Comment: You send `filter_id` but expect `filter` in your controller

Comment: What do your error logs say? A Server Error 500 normally means your PHP code is failing.

Comment: gestioneUtenti/rotte?filter_id=TLK 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.1.js:8623send jquery-2.1.1.js:8623jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.js:8152jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.1.js:8298(anonymous function) gestioneUtenti:45jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.js:4409elemData.handle

Comment: Take a look at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` for the details of the error

Comment: it should be the return Response::json() ---> if i change the return with a View::make()   the XHR get request pass without error

Comment: Route::get('intranet_admin/gestioneStatoUtenti/rotte/{filter_id}', 'UserController@orderByDrop'); instead of your declaration. Then in your js
$.get('gestioneStatoUtenti/rotte/' + filter_id, function(data). Then in your controller public function orderByDrop($filter_id) { $fetchFilter = User::orderBy($filter_id)->get();
 try it

Comment: @mattiaorsi Again, what does the error log (`app/storage/logs/laravel.log`) show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Response::json()` expects an array, however you are passing an object.

In Laravel `Model::orderBy()->get()` will return an Eloquent Collection Object which has array like behaviour. To resolve this you just need to tell the collection to return itself as an array and not a collection object.

`$fetchFilter = User::orderBy($selectedValue)->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Response::json() automatically format the collection as an array. Sometimes I don't toArrayfy my collection before returning a json Response and it works fine.

Comment: @KeizerBridge not according to the api docs `string|array $data` http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.html#method_json

Comment: They do all for lazy dev.

Comment: -- The format separator does not match The format separator does not match -- if i convert eloquent ->toArray()

Comment: solved by changing Eloquent to QueryBuilder for MSSQL server   $fetchUtenti = DB::table('Name_Table')->orderBy($selectedValue)->get();